# Why do I miss rows if I split a dataframe on a condition and the opposite?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I have a dataframe `df` which I want to split.

| Product | Category |
| --- | --- |
| A | non-food |
| B | food |
| C | non-food |
| D | NULL |
| ... | .... |
| XYZ | NULL |

Therefore I have the following code:

```
print(df.count())
-> 150.000

filter_cr = (df["Category"].isNull()) & (df["Category"] != "food")

df_food = df.filter(filter_cr)
print(df_food.count())
-> 120.000

df_non_food = df.filter(~filter_cr)
print(df_food.count())
-> 22.000
```

No I try to understand where my **8.000** missing rows are. Anybody an idea?

BR

Comment: Do you want `&` or do you want `|`?

Comment: It might help if you identified *which* 8.000 rows are missing.

Comment: According to the posted code, `df_food.count()` has 2 different values.

Comment: because you have `df["Category"] != "food"` in condition, spark will automatically add `df.category is not null` condition.  Try doing `df.filter(filter_cr).explain()`.  It will show you something like this `(isnotnull(Category) AND (isnull(Category) AND NOT (Category = food)` in physical plan.  @C.Nivs has a good point. I think your condition is not quite making sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I miss rows if I split a dataframe on a condition and the opposite?

As @Emma said if you us `.explain()` of pyspark dataframe explain **it Prints the (logical and physical) plans to the console for debugging purpose.**

In below image you can see for your condition logical plan contains 2 sub conditions it check is category is not null and category is null and not equal to food `(isnotnull(Category) AND (isnull(Category) AND NOT (Category = food)))` and for opposite of its logical plan contains 2 sub conditions it check category is not null or it equal to food `(isnotnull(Category#341) OR (Category#341 = food))`

**Because of it we are getting some rows less for opposite condition.**

[image]